# Getting Failure to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/

Tags: syslinux, ros

While trying to install some packages of TB3 on Raspberry pi  3B+, And while giving the command "sudo apt install net-tools", I am getting the following two errors:

1. Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/n/net-tools_1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb. Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
2. Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try --fix-missing?

I checked the interent it is working(looked at the router) and while trying to use the command "sudo apt update", still I am getting the same error with other errors as well. I request to kindly help me asap.

Comment: It can be a temporary failure just like the error message suggests. So, try again later.

Answer (score 0):

I found routing with NAT broke name resolution. This fixed it for me:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -d 127.0.0.53 -o lo -m comment --comment "SNAT for systemd-resolved" -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.1
```

You may need to change the insertion number which for my POSTROUTING was 1 to insert before the only post route entry in my case.